# D3.js Orthographic projection and artefacts?

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I have an issue with the representation of a geoJSON file (milky way).

It seems that the contours are, in some cases (depending on the rotation), misinterpreted or actually closed the wrong way. See the attached screenshots and the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdYmqL where you can manually rotate the projection.

We can also see the artefact in d3-celestial (https://github.com/ofrohn/d3-celestial) here:
http://armchairastronautics.blogspot.de/p/skymap.html

Does anybody know what happens?  Any solution?  Thanks ;)

Code:

```
var path = d3.geoPath()
         .projection(d3.geoOrthographic());

g.selectAll("path")
.data(milkyWayGeoJson.features)
.enter().append('path')
.attr("class", "mw")
.attr("d", path);
```

[image: No Problem]
[image: Problem]